# sql server get most popular doctor and number of patients

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have patients that have doctors. I want to get the doctor that have the most patients and also the number of patient that he has. Is there a way of doing this without using select TOP. primary key(SSN), DoctorLicenceNo->doctor id. The table is the following.
PATIENT (SSN, FirstName, LastName, Address, DateOfBirth, DoctorLicenceNo)

I did this query

```
SELECT DoctorLicenceNo ,MAX(c)
FROM(
SELECT DoctorLicenceNo ,COUNT(SSN) c
FROM
PATIENT
GROUP BY
DoctorLicenceNo) as temp
```

i get the following. How I can get the DoctorLicenceNo in the result set.

```
Column 'temp.DoctorLicenceNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DoctorLicenceNo ,MAX(c)
FROM(
SELECT DoctorLicenceNo ,COUNT(SSN) c
FROM
PATIENT
GROUP BY
DoctorLicenceNo) as temp
GROUP BY DoctorLicenceNo
```

I think you are just missing the `GROUP BY` on the outer query since you are calling the `MAX(c)` hard to test w/o the actual data though :)